# DatabaseError using SQLalchemy when trying to use engine to connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a local MySQL server inside a Docker container. This container is from the "mysql/mysqlserver" image and is set to port 3306. I'm trying to connect to this server using the SQLalchemy library so that I can manipulate the database using Python, however it returns a database error when I try to use the engine object to access the database.

The code I'm using to create the engine is:

```
def mysql_engine_generator():
    return create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:XXXXX@localhost:3306/mysql", echo=True) 

engine = mysql_engine_generator()
```

And then I try to execute a simple SQL statement like so:

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("CREATE TABLE some_table (x int, y int)"))
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111)
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

I went to the link indicated in the error message and It tells me the error must be in the dialect or the database driver, not in SQLalchemy itself. However, I'm using the driver and dialect combination recommended by the official MySQL documentation, so I have no idea how that could be wrong.

I tried manipulating the database using the MySQL CLI. The command "mysql> CREATE TABLE some_table (x int, y int)" worked just fine and the table was properly created, which tells me there was nothing wrong with the SQL statement or with the database itself.

I tried using "mysqldb" instead of "mysqlconnector" thinking it may the correct driver here. It gave me an operational error instead of the Database error:

```
OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I also tried using the "pymysql" driver, which gave me the fellowing error:

```
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: Does your code behave any differently if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` ?

Comment: @GordThompson, nope, same thing unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, so just to be clear: The MySQL server is running inside the Docker container but your Python code is running outside of the container. Is that correct?

Comment: @GordThompson yes, exactly.

Comment: So when you do `docker ps` do you have an entry in the PORTS column that looks like `0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp` ?

Comment: @GordThompson the PORTS column shows "3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp" for this MySQL container.

Comment: It sounds like your `docker run` command is missing `-p 3306:3306` to make the server accessible from the outside world.